# How to throw an error if there is a NAN in Fortran?

Tags: fortran, nan

I want my Fortran program to warn me if some calculation results in a `NAN` value. I have naively tried:

```
if(a==NAN) write(*,*) 'error'
```

and

```
if(a=='NAN') write(*,*) 'error'
```

but both obviously failed: in the first the compiler asks what type is `NAN`, while inn the second I try to compare a number with a character, and obviously the compiler complains.

How can I do it?

Comment: Lookup the intrinsic `IEEE_IS_NAN` in the Fortran [standard](https://j3-fortran.org/doc/year/18/18-007r1.pdf), section 17.11.13. I suggest to have a look at the whole section 17 on IEEE arithmetic.

Comment: In this case, the linked question contains the answer for what you want to do.  However, the answers consider aspects of your attempts in this question (the pre-Fortran 2003 way).  Try the form in the question first.